# Am I allowed to post an entire project instead of portions of code in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions, code, project

There is a project (Objective-C, made with xcode) that I messed up, there are runtime errors to correct.

But the project is so big, the code is huge. Am I allowed to attach a zip file containing the whole xcode project, instead of posting all the code?

Comment: Noooooo please don't. But thanks for asking here beforehand!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not recommended. Stack Overflow is not your personal debugging service. Ideally you should narrow your problem down to a simple, isolated section of code. Something we could try for ourselves without having to wade through your entire project. This also means that if you have a large project, you should not include all your sources within your post. Keep it small.

And please don't "hide" your code in a zip file which we have to download from somewhere. Your posts should be self-contained. Should the link to your zip-file ever go down, then your question is no longer valid and useful to others. We can after all no longer see the actual sources that you are having a problem with.

And as stated by @sixlettervariables, downloading zip files is not really something many like to do to begin with. You never know what you might drag onto your computer. (Malware, viruses, trojans, pictures of cats) So they are best avoided.

Comment: Zip files are also a potential source of malware, viruses, and/or trojans. Bare source code in a text box is not (or far less likely, don't hack me bro).

Comment: @sixlettervariables Valid point. I integrated it.

Answer (score 7):

You should always try to post as little code as possible to explain your question and to allow us to understand your problem.

If possible, provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: [*No.*](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

If you are unable to fit your problem into the question itself, it probably fails either the "specific" or "practical" test for questions. It also fails the test of "reasonably scoped".